# Mass XML Editing using command line tools

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, awk

I have hundreds of xml files, which I want to do a one off edit to in a specific place. Somewhere in each xml file I have something that looks like this.

```
   <SomeTag
     attribute1 = "foo"
     attribute2 = "bar"
     attribute3 = "lol"/>
```

The number of attributes, and their names change depending on the file, but the `SomeTag` doesn't. I'd like to add another attribute after the last attribute.

I realise editing xml this way is silly, but it is just a one off job which I'd like to do with something like `sed`, but I can't figure out the multi-line usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XML shell [xsh](https://metacpan.org/module/PAJAS/XML-XSH2-2.1.6/xsh):

```
for my $file in { glob "*.xml" } {
    open $file ;
    for //SomeTag set @another 'new value' ;
    save :b ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i would use a transformation stylesheet and an identity template (XSLT).

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="SomeTag">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="newAttribute">
      <xsl:value-of select="'whatever'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will copy the entire XML, but will run through the defined template for your 'SomeTag'.

Taken from [here](http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity)

Answer (score 1):

If your input file is really that simple and consistently formatted:

```
$ cat file
foo
   <SomeTag
     attribute1 = "foo"
     attribute2 = "bar"
     attribute3 = "lol"/>
bar

$ gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS= '{sub(/<SomeTag[^/]+/,"&\n     attribute4 = \"eureka\"")}1' file
foo
   <SomeTag
     attribute1 = "foo"
     attribute2 = "bar"
     attribute3 = "lol"
     attribute4 = "eureka"/>
bar
```